# In QAbstractItemModel::data() const, how can i add some thread safe data

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qabstractitemmodel

In QAbstractItemModel::data(), how can i add some thread safe data

QAbstractItemModel::data() is a 'const' function, so I cannot add my scope mutex lock, but my data must be changed in somewhere, so it must be need a mutex lock, how can I solve this issue?

ps: I have tried connect/emit, but the signal also need 'const' keyword, so do i need use TCP socket??

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&cacheMutex_);
    auto cacheTime = logCache_.find(key_);
}
```

Comment: It's typical to make a `mutex` like this `mutable`, as the mutex itself does not change anything internal about the class (i.e. the class has no observable change from holding the `mutex` or not, so it's fine to be `mutable`)

Comment: Oh!!!!it's work,Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code snippet I believe you mean to add some synchronization object as derived class member. If so @Tas' comment is already an answer: synchronization objects are not conceptually considered part of your data, so just mark them mutable in your derived class:

mutable QMutex cacheMutex_;

Data member marked mutable can still be modified in a const member function.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about `QMetaObject`. And always work with UI in the main thread.
Try to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(..., Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection)`, your method will be executed in the main thread.
So you don't need mutex. Thanks!